# Fromstream stream exception "parameter is not valid" when rename .webp to .jpg

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use the following code to save uploaded images to my wwwroot directory in ASP.Net Core 3.1 web application:

```
 var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
 int filesCount = files.Count;

 //Some codes here
 //Check for type of file: only jpg and png are accepted
 for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
 {
     string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[i].FileName).ToLower();
     if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".png")       
      {//Some codes here}
 }

 //some codes here
 
 for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
 {
     using (var stream = files[i].OpenReadStream())
     {
         try
         {
            using (var img = Image.FromStream(stream))
           {
              img.ScaleAndCrop(500, 500)                  
              .SaveAs($"wwwroot\\images\\items\\" + fileName + i + ".jpg", 45);
           }
         }
         catch (Exception message)
         {
            string exceptionMessgae = message.ToString();
         }
     }
 }
```

It works fine and when a client user upload a `.webp` image, the code refuse to save the image correctly, but the problem is when the client manually rename a `Image1.webp` to `Image1.jpg` and then upload it, the system accept the .jpg file and go ahead but on `using (var img = Image.FromStream(stream)` it passes and and exception message  as `"parameter is not valid"` appears and image does not save.
I can't understand, if the  renamed-uploaded image is not .jpg  so why it passed to save code , and if it is .jpg why it can't be saved.

More information: the problem exists even when I rename a `test.dll` file to `test.jpg` file and upload it. I need the code to prevent accepting renamed and fake `.jpg`.

Comment: The first few bytes may identify the file as a real jpg image. Check for those

Comment: Is that the same `Get Mime Type` ?? If not I'll be thankful to get some key words to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first three bytes of a (real) JPG file are [apparently](https://www.file-recovery.com/jpg-signature-format.htm) (hex) FF D8 FF.

This is also called the ["magic number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number), which for [PNG is longer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics): 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a

GetMimeType just uses the (possibly renamed) extension to look up the mimetype in an internal database (which may be incomplete). Windows Explorer also uses just the extension to get the file type to display.

To read that magic number, you don't have to read in the *whole* file into a byte-array, just the first few bytes.